# Python - Adding Widgets will create them in a new window, when using threading.timer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm actually having a problem using threading.Timer() function, in order to repeat an analysis every X minutes.

So the idea is to count a number of operations for an interface, and to do a counting of each category for that same interface. During each repetition of the code, the old values for the categories are removed from the layout (QGridLayout), and new ones are added.

When i click once on the button, it works flawless. But when i activate the threading.Timer() option to repeat the operation automatically, when it comes to add the new QLabel, it adds them as new windows 'pythonw'.

I cannot understand what is happening, as the codes perfectly recognize the layout, delete just fine the old widgets , but when it's time to insert new ones, it inserts them as new windows...

I read that you would eventually need to update the self window when using threading ? Not sure about it, could you guys lend me a hand ??

```
def Configuracion(self,ListBox):
    
    ScrollingArea = self.findChildren(QScrollArea)
    LayoutFrame = ScrollingArea[0].widget().layout()
    
    ColumnaListBox = LayoutFrame.getItemPosition(LayoutFrame.indexOf(ListBox))[1]
    DictValores = {}

    #Quitamos eventuales valores creados antes

    i = 0

    while True:
        try:
            LayoutFrame.itemAtPosition(6 + i, ColumnaListBox).widget().setParent(None) #.deleteLater()
            i += 1
        except:
            break

    for i in range(0,ListBox.count()):
        if not ListBox.item(i).text().split('|')[-1].strip() in DictValores:
            DictValores[ListBox.item(i).text().split('|')[-1].strip()] = 1
        else:
            DictValores[ListBox.item(i).text().split('|')[-1].strip()] += 1

    i = 0
    ListaValor = []

    for clave in sorted(DictValores.keys()):
        Valor = QLabel(clave + ': ' + str(DictValores[clave]) + ' / ' + str(ListBox.count()))
        Valor.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        if 'Error' in clave:
            Valor.setStyleSheet("font: bold;color : red")
        else:
            Valor.setStyleSheet("font: bold;color : green")
            
        LayoutFrame.addWidget(Valor, 6 + i, ColumnaListBox)

    if ListBox.count() == 0:
        Item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        Item.setText('Sin Operaciones por el momento')
        Item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        Item.setFont(font)
        ListBox.addItem(Item)
        
    ListBox.sortItems()
    ListBox.scrollToBottom()
    ListBox.setMinimumWidth(ListBox.sizeHintForColumn(0) + 20)
```

It fails when adding the widget on the 'LayoutFrame.addWidget(Valor, 6 + i, ColumnaListBox)' line, when scheduling an execution after X minutes using threading.Timer(), but does not when executing the code once. I have checked the definition of the ScrollingArea/Frame/Layout, and they are properly recognized, and have the same address, so what could go wrong here ???

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it using a simple QTimer() object... Still curious on what is wrong when using threading, so if somehow would like to share some views on it, would be nice :)